# Why do I get this error? template argument '' is invalid

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create a template with `std::string` as `typename T`, and a `const char`:

test.cpp

```cpp
template <typename T, const char N>
class MyClass
{
public:
    static const char Get()
    {
        return N;
    }
};

template <>
class MyClass<std::string, const char N>
{
public:
    static const char Get()
    { 
        return n;
    }
};
```

test.h

```cpp
int main(){
    const char c = 's';
    std:: cout << MyClass<std::string, c>::Get() << std::endl;
};
```

But I get the following error:

```
template argument 2 is invalid
class MyClass<std::string, const char N>
```

Comment: Why is `main()` in a `.h` file, and the class is in a `.cpp` file? You have your file extensions backwards. In any case, do you have the same error if you pass the character literal *directly* to the template, eg: `MyClass<std::string, 's'>::Get()`? Also, your specialization of `Get()` is returning `n` which is not defined, did you mean `N` instead?

Comment: Since you are only partially specializing the class template it should be `template<const char N> class MyClass<std::string, N>`

Comment: I suggest you to change your question to `Why do I get this error "template argument 2 is invalid" in c++? When trying to create a template with std::string` Honest question from my side, what do you mean by " in your question? I'm not familiar with that notation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

`const` is superfluous as top level modifier for a non-type template parameter. The same thing for the `Get` return type. You also have a small typo where `n` should be `N`. And you switched the header content with the cpp content.

But the main issue is how you specialize your template. What you want is a partial specialization. Here is corrected code:

```
template <typename T, char N>
class MyClass
{
public:
    static char Get() { return N; }
};

template <char N>
class MyClass<std::string, N>
{
public:
    static char Get() {  return N; }
};
```